# React Native base fab as single button

Tags: react-native, native-base

Hi I'm using react native and react native base and I'm trying to use a FAB as a scroll-to-top button -no other action button inside of it-. Understandibly I could use a button, but the FAB is rather simple to set up.

I have the following code:

```
  <Fab
    active="true"
    containerStyle={{ }}
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)' }}
    position="bottomRight"
    onPress={this.scrollToTop.bind(this)}>
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-up" />
  </Fab>
```

When I press the FAB, not only nothing happens, anything that is "clickable" behind it gets triggered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by placing the FAB inside the Container instead of the Content, as mentioned in this link:  http://discuss.nativebase.io/t/how-to-use-a-fab-in-page-with-a-list/237/3.

```
    <Container>
     <Content>
       <List />
       <AnyComponent />
     </Content>
     <Fab/>
   </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a simple view?

```
<View style={{
   position: 'absolute',
   bottom: 30,
   right: 30,
   width: 100, 
   height: 100,
   borderRadius: 50
}}>
<Icon/>
</View>
```

Comment: I have a flatlist, tried you method in different ways without success